# Why doesn't this break work within inline if?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why this `while` loop breaks at first run when using an inline if with two actions (with `break;` being the second):

```
var list = [4, 2, 1, 3];

while (list.length) {
    list.splice(0, 1);
    console.log("length is now: " + list.length);

    if (list.length === 2) console.log("break!"); break;
}
```

Changing the last line to this works fine:

```
if (list.length === 2) break;
```

...and so does this:

```
if (list.length === 2) {
    console.log("break!");
    break;
}
```

AFAIK it's okay to have more than one action inside of an inline if, just like:

```
if (true) console.log("true"); console.log("still true");
```

Comment: Because you need brackets. The if statement just calls the next command. So in your case the break would be called everytime

Comment: @JaromandaX please please don't post such things to beginners. They might start to use them.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token break`
(Don't worry I'm only asking out of curiosity. I always use `{}`, which is why I didn't know about the inline if break...)

Comment: @kraftwer1: Please ignore JaromandaX's example above. You *can* have multiple expressions via the comma operator, but they must be *expressions*, and it's an unreadable, unmaintainable abuse of the comma operator. Please forget you saw it.

Comment: I only wanted to point out that, despite its unreadability, it doesn't even work. I totally agree with it you about the abuse. Still I think a good engineer needs to know about it. I can accept your answer below in three minutes.

Comment: @kraftwer1: Just to explain it: The comma operator is a binary operator that accepts two expressions (left and right). It evaluates both of them, and its result is the value of the right-hand one. Since in JavaScript we have *ExpressionStatement* (an expression used as a statement), you can do something like J's example (just not with `break`, because it's not an expression), for instance `if (condition) console.log('a'), console.log('b');` (because `console.log(...)` is an expression). And sadly, sometimes people do. :-)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the great explanation anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AFAIK it's okay to have more than one action inside of an inline if, just like:

No, it isn't. To do that, you need a block (`{...}`):

```
if (list.length === 2) {
    console.log("break!");
    break;
}
```

Control-flow statements like `if` accept a *single statement* as the body. That statement can be a *block* if you need to make the body multiple statements long.

Doesn't matter how you write it (except as a matter of style, readability, and maintainability):

```
if (list.length === 2) { console.log("break!"); break; }
```

Linebreaks are almost entirely ignored by the JavaScript parser (*almost* because of Automatic Semicolon Insertion, which is where the parser is expected to correct code with missing semicolons if it finds line breaks where they should be).

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but why does this work then: `if (true) console.log("true"); console.log("still true");`

Comment: @kraftwer1 are you sure that second console.log is even in the if statement? There's no reason for it not to run.

Comment: @kraftwer1: Because both statements always execute. The first because `if (true)` is always true, and the second because it's not related to the `if` in any way. If both were controlled by the `if`, then `if (false) console.log("false"); console.log("still false");` wouldn't output anything, but of course it does (`"still false"`).

Comment: Okay that totally makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

The inline if statement stops executing after the first statement if there are no curly braces present.

Example:

```
if (list.length === 2) console.log("break!"); break;
```

This will make the console.log run as the only statement and will not be able to reach the other break; statement.

It's almost never a good thing to use an inline if statement WITHOUT curly braces

```
if (list.length === 2) {console.log("break!"); break;}
```

Get into the habit of writing your if-statements with curly braces. You won't regret it!

Writing inline if statements without curly braces can give some unwanted behavior and is hard to maintain. Also, it's not fun to read. We need curly braces.

Hope this helps!